# German National Visa - Internship or guest researcher?

Tags: visas, germany

I have a fellowship offer for a 4-month stay at a German research organisation (non-profit). Since, I am staying for more than 90 days I need a "[German National Visa](http://www.india.diplo.de/Vertretung/indien/en/06__Consu__Visa/visa__new/NATIONAL/NATIONAL.html)". I am confused as to what type of German National Visa visa to apply. The two most appropriate visas look to be - [Internship](http://www.india.diplo.de/contentblob/4060714/Daten/3744371/training.pdf) or a [Guest Researcher/Scientist](http://www.india.diplo.de/contentblob/4061608/Daten/3744375/guestscientist.pdf). I am a Masters in Computer Science on the verge of completing my doctorate. I will be submitting my thesis before I leave for this fellowship.

I repeatedly mention fellowship as the offer letter states the following

1. We invite the candidate for a fellowship (not an internship)
2. Funding for fellowship is provided through public funding

Comment: Why not send an email to the German consulate and ask them?

Comment: Thanks, I have done that. I was wondering if someone could throw some light on the situation.

Comment: Why don't you ask your german research org? I am currently looking at a research fellowship that lasts beyond a year in France -- my research lab suggested a "long stay visa".

Comment: I did ask my research organisation. I am yet to receive a reply. I will update their answer once I receive it. I am looking for a community perspective.

Comment: @drN Both are long-stay visas (i.e. not Schengen visas for up to 90 days), the question is which one.

Comment: I have applied for a German National Visa as well and it has been about 7 weeks and 4 days now. I do not have any kind of reply yet from them. Can you please let me know how long it took for your visa to be accepted? Thanks.

Comment: It took 72 hours. Please note and understand the there are different types of national visas and I applied for the "Guest Scientist" visa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, here's what happened.

My research organisation said I should apply for a [student visa](http://www.india.diplo.de/Vertretung/indien/en/06__Consu__Visa/visa__new/NATIONAL/NATIONAL.html). I was totally taken aback and surprised. In fact, they mentioned that past fellows have applied for a [student visa](http://www.india.diplo.de/Vertretung/indien/en/06__Consu__Visa/visa__new/NATIONAL/NATIONAL.html) and that'd be the best. However, the student visa is an arduous process with elaborate mark sheet checking procedures.

In the meanwhile, I got a reply from the German Embassy that I can apply for a [guest scientist](http://www.india.diplo.de/Vertretung/indien/en/06__Consu__Visa/visa__new/NATIONAL/NATIONAL.html) visa. This seems much better and I will proceed my application with this. In addition, I am also [eligible for a visa fee waiver](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/cae/servlet/contentblob/480896/publicationFile/150773/Gebuehrenmerkblatt.pdf) (P1, point b) as I am a foreign national receiving a scholarship from public funds to stay/work in Germany. However, the German embassy confirmed that such a waiver can only be decided after the visa officer goes through my documents. I spoke about this to my research organisation and they said that I should do as the embassy suggested or in other words apply for a guest scientist visa.

Moral of the story - Don't blindly apply for a visa, read through rules/regulations and options. It could save you time as well as money.